# Помогите написать выражение в .htaccess

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Были страница с `url` вида `сайт/?cPath=1116`
стали  `сайт/?cat=1116`

пробую

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?cPath=([0-9]+)?$ ^index.php?cat=$1 [R=301,L]
```

не получается

Comment: Просто отличная статья:  
http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/  
Если интересно- прочтите, а ошибка в символе крышки в начале строки, которой надо заменить.

Comment: на что заменить?
RewriteRule index.php\?cPath=([0-9]+) index.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule %index.php\?cPath=([0-9]+) index.php?cat=$1 
не работает (((

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?cat\=([^/]*)$ /index.php?cPath=$1 [L]
```

Пример

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?cPath=1116
http://www.domain.com/index.php?cat=1116
```

Answer (score 0):

Не будет работать только потому, что аргументы ссылки не попадают в RewriteRule

Вам нужно вот такое:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cPath=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php index.php?cat=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Не работает ((
но еще используется 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.сайт\.com\.ua$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/сайт\.com\.ua\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт\.com\.ua$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.сайт\.com\.ua$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "http\:\/\/сайт\.com\.ua\/" [R=301,L]

т.е 301 сам по себе на сервере работает

Comment: @kovalsky_2013 у меня работает. Скрипт простой, подводных камней не вижу. Смотрите у себя. Ваши правила вроде не затрагивают моё.